# Django is doing something weird with my DATABASES settings

Tags: django, sqlite, database-migration, django-syncdb, django-pyodbc

I want to switch db backends from django_pyodbc to sqlite in order to make sure my custom user model works before I start messing around with my db. So I commented out the DATABASES setting and put in a new one which uses sqlite. I've done this before (on this project as well) with no problems, but now I have no idea what's going on.

`syncdb` responds as if it is looking at a db that has already been synced, i.e. it does nothing.

In  `shell`, settings.DATABASES returns the settings for my original db (shockingly, it still thinks I'm using the sqlserver_ado backend which I switched out for django_pyodbc a couple of weeks ago), and I can access models which don't have any relation to my user model, but those that do return an error (because I changed some user field names). In the traceback I see that it is still looking at the MSSQL db.

`runserver` works, but when I go to a page I get a DatabaseError - no such table: django_session. The exception location is in ...\django\db\backends\sqlite3\...

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  187.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py" in process_response
  28.                 if request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close():
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in get_expire_at_browser_close
  253.         if self.get('_session_expiry') is None:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in get
  57.         return self._session.get(key, default)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in _get_session
  168.                 self._session_cache = self.load()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in load
  18.                 expire_date__gt=timezone.now()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in get
  143.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  398.         num = len(clone)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  106.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in iterator
  317.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in results_iter
  775.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  41.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  366.             six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  362.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
```

And yes; I *have* tried turning my computer on and off again. Any ideas? Thank you.

== EDIT ==

Here are my DATABASES settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': PROJECT_ROOT.child('temp_db').child('sqlite.db'),
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.django_pyodbc',
#         'NAME': my_project,
#         'USER': '',
#         'PASSWORD': '',
#         'HOST': my_host,
#         'PORT': '',
#         'OPTIONS': {
#             'driver': 'SQL Server',
#             'MARS_Connection': True,
#         }
#     }
# }
```

== EDIT2 ==

I looked in my settings folder to find `__init__.py`, `base.py`, `dev.py` and their associated .pyc files. In addition, there is a `settings.pyc` file with no corresponding .py file (I'm assuming this is a remnant from before I chopped up `settings.py` into seperate pieces. I tried deleting it and doing `syncdb` again and got this:

```
C:\...\my_project>manage.py syncdb --settings=my_project.settings.devettings=web_ems.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\my_project\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    if settings.DEBUG:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s"% (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))

ImportError: Could not import settings 'my_project.settings.settings' (Is it on sys
.path?): No module named settings
```

Comment: Show us your `settings.py`.

Comment: `DATABASES` would do.

Comment: When running the `shell`, type `from my_project import settings; settings` and check the file name.

Comment: my_project\my_project\settings\\__init__.pyc

Comment: Is it the right path? (You don't have to show me, I can't know.) Also, are you sure you are not redefining `DATABASES` somewhere else? If, when using the shell, `settings.DATABASES` is not what you expect, then either `settings` is the wrong module or `DATABASES` is being replaced.

Comment: Or to give the full response: `<module 'my_project.settings' from 'C:\...\my_project\my_project\settings\__init__.pyc'>`

Comment: The path is correct, and I'm not redefining `DATABASES` anywhere else. See my latest edit

Comment: Actually I tell a lie, I was redefining the settings module elsewhere! In `manage.py`: `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings.settings")`. I changed `settings.settings` to `settings.dev` and all is swell. I want to kick myself! Thank you @AndreaCorbellini for getting me there. If you put an answer up I'll accept it

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the right settings module, therefore the changes you make will not have any effect.

The possible causes can be many, however the main possibilities are two:

1. You are using a module from the wrong location (i.e. your `PYTHONPATH` is wrong);
2. Your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is wrong.

**Bonus tip:** if you want to know what settings module you are using, open the shell and type:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.SETTINGS_MODULE
'my_project.settings'
```

Then, if you want to know whether you are using `my_project.settings` from the right path, use:

```
>>> from my_project import settings
>>> settings
<module 'my_project.settings' from '...'>
```